# C# SQL Subtract Product Quantity at FIFO

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I just wondering how to subtract quantity of the same product with different date expiration.

Example

Table **Inventory**:

```
Product | Qty | Expiration |
--------+-----+------------+
Oreo    | 2   | 10/18/2017 |
Oreo    | 6   | 10/09/2017 |
```

I have request to table `Inventory` of `Oreo` with qty of 7. That 7 Oreo request
must be subtracted to first to expire which is 10/09/2017. My request has remaining of 1 Oreo will be subtracted to next expiration which is 10/18/2017 so the table will be like this

```
Product | Qty | Expiration |
--------+-----+------------+
Oreo    | 1   | 10/18/2017 |
Oreo    | 0   | 10/09/2017 |
```

Comment: Are you looking for an SQL solution or a C# solution? If so what frameworks are you using? And - what have you tried already?

Comment: C# solution . What do you mean of framework?
I just tried to FIFO by date

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that :

1. You're working with MySQL database.
2. Using MySQL Connector / .Net.
3. Assuming you have a Primary ID in your table
   Id |  Product | Qty | Expiration |
   ---+----------+-----+------------+
   1 | Oreo     | 1   | 10/18/2017 |
   2 | Oreo     | 0   | 10/09/2017 |

Here's a function i've written to demonstrate you the logic you need :

```
// Function to get all the product listing for a given product name in ascending order
public void UpdateProductListing(string myConnString, String productName, Int productQty)  
{

    MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(myConnString);
    MySqlCommand myCommand = (MySqlCommand)myConnection.CreateCommand();
    // Warning : never use String query, instead use parametrized query by calling myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Product, Qty, Expiration FROM YourDb.YourTable ORDER BY Expiration ASC";
    myConnection.Open();

    // The reader enables us to acces each row by calling it's read method
    MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    try 
    {
            // QtyRemaining variable will hold how much of the quatity is to be taken from next row.
            Int QtyRemaining = productQty;

            // Always call Read before accessing data.
            while (myReader.Read()) 
            {                    
                if (myReader.GetInt16(2) >= productQty)
                {
                    Int NewQty = myReader.GetInt16(2) - productQty;
                    // At this moment i'm not sure if you need to close the reader before Inserting.
                    // Anyways you'll require to arrange this code in a proper order to suite your situation
                    MySqlCommand InsertCommand = (MySqlCommand) myConnection.CreateCommand();

                    // Warning : never use String query, instead use parametrized query by calling myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue
                    InsertCommand.CommandText = "Insert INTO YourDb.YourTable (Qty) VALUES (" + NewQty.toString()  + ") WHERE Id=" + myReader.GetInt16(0).toString();
                    InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Now we know that this particular row cannot supply the entire qty, so we'll set it to zero and move to next row for remaining qty
                    MySqlCommand InsertCommand = (MySqlCommand) myConnection.CreateCommand();

                    // Warning : never use String query, instead use parametrized query by calling myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue
                    InsertCommand.CommandText = "Insert INTO YourDb.YourTable (Qty) VALUES (" + 0.toString()  + ") WHERE Id=" + myReader.GetInt16(0).toString();
                    InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    
                    // the quantity to be captured from next row
                    QtyRemaining =  productQty - myReader.GetInt16(2);
                }                    
            }
    }
    finally 
    {
            // always call Close when done reading.
            myReader.Close();

            // Close the connection when done with it.
            myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Notes :

1. This code might get you several errors if you try to compile it directly. Please consider it as a reference for the logic.
2. Always use Paramterized SQL Queries. For the .Net MySQL connector refer : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html
3. You might require to close the Reader to execute queries.
4. It will be better to create a Product class, and write this logic there.

Comment: I am using MS SQL

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL version would look like this (again, lots of assumptions, as we can't see what your table structure actually looks like):

```
private void SubtractInventory(string product, int qty)
{
    string connectionString = "connection sting goes here";
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = $"select ID, PRODUCT, QTY, EXPIRES from PRODUCTS order by EXPIRES asc";

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn))
            {
                using (DataTable tempTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    adapter.Fill(tempTable);
                    if (tempTable.Rows.Count == 0) throw new Exception("No such product.");

                    foreach (DataRow r in tempTable.Rows)
                    {
                        int newQty = (int)r["QTY"] - qty;
                        if (newQty >= 0)
                        {
                            r["QTY"] = newQty;
                            qty = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            qty = qty - (int)r["QTY"];
                            r["QTY"] = 0;
                        }
                    }

                    if (qty > 0) throw new Exception($"Not enough of {product} in inventory to subtract {qty}.");

                    using (SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
                    {
                        adapter.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
                        adapter.Update(tempTable);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // log ex.Message somehow..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for calculation.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  *,
        CumulativeSum= SUM(Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Expiration  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
    FROM Inventory
)
SELECT Product,  
    Qty = CASE 
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - @request) < 0 THEN 0
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - @request) BETWEEN 0 AND Qty THEN (CumulativeSum - @request)
            ELSE Qty 
           END 
    , Expiration
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Product, Expiration
```

Update Table script:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  *,
        CumulativeSum= SUM(Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Expiration  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
    FROM Inventory
)
UPDATE 
    CTE
SET
    Qty = CASE 
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - @request) < 0 THEN 0
            WHEN (CumulativeSum - @request) BETWEEN 0 AND Qty THEN (CumulativeSum - @request)
            ELSE Qty 
           END 
FROM CTE
WHERE CumulativeSum <= Qty + @request
```

Comment: It subtract but its not update the column qty in the database

Comment: how can i get the expiration of a the first product that expire?

`Product | Qty | Expiration |`

`--------+-----+------------+`

`Oreo    | 1   | 10/18/2017 |`

`Oreo    | 0   | 10/09/2017 |`

and update to my request product?

Comment: You can use SqlDataAdapter or DataReader. You can use this script like any select query.